# How to change my calendar to icelandic traditional in linux

Tags: linux, calendar, locale, monthcalendar, yearmonth

This is similar to what Svante Janson described in the article: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=8c996f399e30ccc6c55164bb8e169fa5ff398168

|  | Icelandic | begins | Gregorian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | Harpa | Thursday | 19–25 April |
| S2 | Skerpla | Saturday | 19–25 May |
| S3 | Sólmánuður | Monday | 18–24 June |
| S4 | Heyannir | Sunday | 23–30 July |
| S5 | Tvímánuður | Tuesday | 22–29 August |
| S6 | Haustmánuður | Thursday | 21–28 September |
| W1 | Gormánuður | Saturday | 21–28 October |
| W2 | Ýlir | Monday | 20–27 November |
| W3 | Mörsugur | Wednesday | 20–27 December |
| W4 | Þorri | Friday | 19–26 January |
| W5 | Góa | Sunday | 18–25 February |
| W6 | Einmánuður | Tuesday | 20–26 March |

I don't want to live according to the emperors' calendar.

Comment: What system do you want to change you calendar on?

Comment: The ArchLinuxARM.